# Condition sometimes failing to test if a specific process is running or not

Tags: shell-script, process, livecd, xubuntu

I can't understand why my script, **sometimes**, won't recognize if my Firefox is running. Analyzing the stdout I could state that this condition (`if ps cax | grep firefox > /dev/null`) sometimes is skipped even when my Firefox is running.

Currently using Xubuntu 18.10 Livecd

The script called at startup.

```
#!/bin/bash 

[[ -f /home/xubuntu/controle_memoria.lock ]] && exit 1
> /home/xubuntu/controle_memoria.lock

while true ; do 
free=`free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print $4}'`
if [ "$free" -gt 0 ]
 then
    if [ $free -le 120 ]; #When my memory consuptiom goes below 120MB do the commands below. 
     then

if ps cax | grep firefox > /dev/null
then
        sudo killall -9 firefox-bin         
        firefox &> /dev/null &

else
    echo "Stopped"
fi

        sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3
        sudo sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches 



    fi
fi & sleep 1; done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ps has `-C` option without need to grep
2. `killall -0 firefox-bin` will tell you if firefox-bin process exist by exit code. Without need of pipe and redirection in a raw.
3. Just remove your `if ps` and leave `killall -9 firefox-bin && firefox-bin &> /dev/null &`. So if process will not be killed, it wouldn't be started.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you replace your `if ps` block with

```
for proc in /proc/*
do
    if [[ $(readlink -f ${proc}/exe) = "/usr/bin/firefox-bin" ]]
        sudo killall -9 firefox-bin
        firefox &> /dev/null &
    else
        echo "Stopped"
    fi
done
```

This removes trying to  parse `ps` output.